# Chess GUI recommendation for linux

Tags: software, online-chess, computer-chess, online, linux

Which chess GUI will be good for Linux. I have tried a lot of GUI's, but as I am new at computer chess, I have no idea about pros and cons of chess GUI's.

Which is chess GUI will you recommend? Is that free? Is that opensource?

Comment: What exactly do you need a chess GUI for? As far as I understand chess GUI allow you to play against a computer engine or against players (human and silicon) on FICS/ICC. I do neither, so don't have a GUI installed. I do play against humans on lichess (via browser or app on phone) and use scid as a database/learning tool (which does interface with an engine). My point is, are you sure that you need a GUI?

Comment: There is chess arena, which has a linux build. It's not super user friendly or eye catchy, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

I used http://www.pychess.org/download/ and https://sourceforge.net/projects/scidvspc/.

Linux chess applications are generally free and open source.

Comment: I just tried pychess but it didn't want to analyse my game. I want to do the moves that I wrote down during my RL game and have it constantly analyse and tell me the evaluation. But instead it started to play back. After I took back the move that the engine had done I could input my game (the engine didn't play anymore) but neither did it analyse anything. There was no way to get it to analyse again. Totally broken imho.

Comment: Try nocheto from nocheto.sallyx.org. But its not free and open source btw :D